# One-sided time series trend-seasonal decomposition

Tags: python, time-series, forecasting

*TL;DR: Are there one-sided decomposition alternatives to the naive `seasonal_decompose` from statsmodels? Are there approaches to adapt intrinsically two-sided algorithms (like `STL` from statsmodels) to forecasting applications?*

I'm attempting to perform time-series forecasting. For this I want to decompose a time-series into trend and seasonal parts. I picked [STL](https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.tsa.seasonal.STL.html) implementation from statsmodels to handle this. I gravitated towards STL instead of [seasonal_decompose](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.seasonal.seasonal_decompose.html), since even the docs down the bottom encourage more sophisticated approaches:
[image: Notes section of seasonal_decompose documentation]
I noticed, however, that the decomposition is two-sided, i.e., the trend and seasonal computation uses data from both before and after a given point in time. Below is an illustration of this using Civilian Labor Force Level from [FRED](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/CLF16OV) and the onset of COVID.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader.fred import FredReader
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import STL


# Load data.
indicator = 'CLF16OV'
data = FredReader(indicator, start=2000).read()

# Execute decomposition.
stl = STL(endog=data, period=12)
decomp = stl.fit()

# Split results into separate series.
data_t = pd.Series(
    data=decomp.trend,
    index=data.index,
    name=f'{indicator}_t',
)
data_s = pd.Series(
    data=decomp.seasonal,
    index=data.index,
    name=f'{indicator}_s',
)
data_r = pd.Series(
    data=decomp.resid,
    index=data.index,
    name=f'{indicator}_r',
)

# Plot results.
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=5, ncols=1, sharex=True, figsize=(11, 10))
axes = axes.flatten()

data.plot(ax=axes[0])
axes[0].set_title('Observed')
axes[0].axvline('02-2020', color='red')
axes[0].annotate('Start of COVID', xy=(0.8, 0.2), xycoords='axes fraction')

data_t.plot(ax=axes[1])
axes[1].set_title('Trend')
axes[1].axvline('02-2020', color='red')
axes[1].axvspan('07-2019', '02-2020', color='red', alpha=0.3)

data_s.plot(ax=axes[2])
axes[2].set_title('Seasonal')
axes[2].axvline('02-2020', color='red')
axes[2].axvspan('03-2018', '02-2020', color='red', alpha=0.3)

data_s.rolling(24).var().plot(ax=axes[3])
axes[3].set_title('Seasonal 2-year rolling variance')
axes[3].axvline('02-2020', color='red')
axes[3].axvspan('03-2018', '02-2020', color='red', alpha=0.3)

data_r.plot(ax=axes[4])
axes[4].set_title('Residua')
axes[4].axvline('02-2020', color='red')

fig.tight_layout()
```

The resulting figure:
[image: Trend-season decomposition of US Labor Force data.]

You'll notice that the trend turns down a couple months before the start of COVID and the variance of the seasonal part picks up even earlier "in anticipation" of the COVID crash.

I don't see a `two_sided` argument for `STL` such as there is for `seasonal_decompose`, which I could set to `False` in order for the algorithm to only "see" past data. I believe this is dictated by some theoretical limitations which I'm ignorant of. The problem with developing a forecasting model using such a centered method is that future states affect the decomposition (and consequently the forecast) at a given point in time and hence I can't use it to form an actionable prediction today.

Are there other options for one-sided decomposition besides the naive `seasonal_decompose`?

Are there approaches to adapt these intrinsically two-sided algorithms to forecasting applications?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need an ETS model which has trend and seasonal components which are estimated in a one-sided manner, and is a common forecasting model.

They are implemented in the statsmodels package for python.

Comment: Thanks Rob, I'll look into them!